# VBA with SQL Server - error 3265 when retrieving data with public serverrole

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

My issue is the following. I have an Excel App, which accesses a MSSQL DB. Using MSSQL Server 2014. I have the following settings and code which work perfectly:

user with serverrole public and sysadmin;

Plus the following code:

```
With rsData
    .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
    .Open "SELECT [VersionNumber],[Date] FROM Main WHERE IsLastCurrent = 1;"
    version_sql = rsData.Fields("VersionNumber").Value
    date_sql = rsData.Fields("Date").Value
End With
```

What is the problem? I want to make the user with a server role just "public" and to remove "sysadmin", because it seems that with the sysadmin it can see more DBs. Thus, I have removed the checkbox of the sysadmin square.

The problem is that, if I use the code above code I get exactly this (it is in German, it is also not my mother tongue, but you would probably get it):

```
Error -2147217911 (Die SELECT-Berechtigung wurde für das main-Objekt, MYDB-Datenbank, dbo-Schema, verweigert.) in procedure GetDataFromSQLServer of Sub cls_Version
```

The error is on line ".Open "SELECT"
If I change the code to:

```
With rsData
    .ActiveConnection = cnLogs
    .Open "USE MYDB SELECT [VersionNumber],[Date] FROM Main WHERE IsLastCurrent = 1;"
    version_sql = rsData.Fields("VersionNumber").Value
    date_sql = rsData.Fields("Date").Value
End With
```

I get and error on the next line (version_sql=rsData):

```
Error 3265 (Ein Objekt, das dem angeforderten Namen oder dem Ordinalverweis entspricht, kann nicht gefunden werden.) in procedure GetDataFromSQLServer of Sub cls_Version
```

Any ideas why those two errors happen? And how to make my user public only and allow him do the same stuff? This is just a simple SELECT query, he should not be an admin to do it.

Thanks for reading it until here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that my public role did not have ability to select. Thus with the following:

```
USE MYDB;
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Main TO UserName;
```

Everything seems to be running as I want - the public user can see only what I want and the query runs ok.
Anyhow, if you know why I had to use "USE MYDB" in the second query, I would be still interested in the answer...